# '@types/chartjs-plugin-waterfall@latest' is not in the npm registry

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, chart.js, node-modules

I am trying to use `chartjs-plugin-waterfall` with angular. I have installed both chartjs & waterfall plugin as followed in [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P91E0.png). I am getting the following errors.

Error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'chartjs-plugin-waterfall'.
>
> 'd:/Angular/newProjClone/practice01/node_modules/chartjs-plugin-waterfall/lib/chartjs-plugin-waterfall.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-plugin-waterfall` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'chartjs-plugin-waterfall'`;

running `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-plugin-waterfall` gives the below error

```
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fchartjs-plugin-waterfall - Not found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  '@types/chartjs-plugin-waterfall@latest' is not in the npm registry.

npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404 

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\karth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-18T16_32_42_150Z-debug.log
```

What am i missing here?